# C# Can't get RegEx working for all cases

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following Data for example:

> HRB 760468: CANNSITE GmbH, Stuttgart, c/o Dr. Elvira Ehle, Rotdornweg 7, 18119 Rostock. Gesellschaft mit beschränkter Haftung. Gesellschaftsvertrag vom 09.03.2017.
>
> HRB 760481: Neckarsee 399. V V GmbH, Stuttgart, Kurt-Schumacher-Straße 18-20, 53113 Bonn. Gesellschaft mit beschränkter Haftung. Gesellschaftsvertrag vom 22.03.2017.

I need to filter out:

> HRB 760468: CANNSITE GmbH, Stuttgart, c/o Dr. Elvira Ehle, Rotdornweg 7, 18119 Rostock
>
> HRB 760481: Neckarsee 399. V V GmbH, Stuttgart, Kurt-Schumacher-Straße 18-20, 53113 Bonn

My RegEx is: `@"HRB.\d+:[^.]+"`

So the problem is with the case "Dr. Elvira" as it contains a "." - the Regex will stop there and not right before "Gesellschaft mit" and I can't get it working to change the Regex to get it to the "Rostock"/"Bonn" at the End in this case.

After that I try to filter out "760468", "CANNSITE GmbH", "Stuttgart", "Rotdornweg 7", "18119"
For that I'm doing the following - maybe you can help me improving this (order is like the data above):

```
     Regex regexNummer = new Regex(@"\d+:");
     Regex regexFirma = new Regex(@":[^,]+");
     Regex regexStadt = new Regex(@", \w+.\w+.\w+.\w+,");
     Regex regexAdresse = new Regex(@", \w+.+\d,");
     Regex regexPlz = new Regex(@", \d+[^ ]+");
     string nummer = regexNummer.Match(match.Value).ToString().Replace(":", "");
     string firma = regexFirma.Match(match.Value).ToString().Replace(": ", "");
     string plz = regexPlz.Match(match.Value).ToString().Replace(", ", "");
     string stadt = regexStadt.Match(match.Value).ToString().Replace(", ", "");
     stadt = stadt.Replace(",", "");
     
     string adresse = regexAdresse.Match(match.Value).ToString();
     adresse = adresse.Remove(adresse.Length - 1);
     adresse = adresse.Substring(adresse.LastIndexOf(", ") + 1);
     adresse = adresse.Substring(1);
```

Because there are so many different types of addresses it often cracks up.

Comment: Address parsing is hard, but it looks like you just need to get to the end of the address.  So, skip over everything else: determine what is unique about that last ".".  Is there something common in what precedes?  For instance, will it always be 5 digits-space-single word? (e.g. "53113 Bonn"). If so, you can locate it like that.  And when all else fails http://regex101.com

Comment: Is your data on a single line or multiple lines? From the example above, it appears it's a multi line.

Comment: Take a look here: https://pastebin.com/cBHHuENL There is the whole example and I explain a little what I want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have some kind of zip code before the city name. You can potentially exploit that for your regex.

The below Regex works fine to extract the first portion from both your examples.

```
Regex.Match(txt, @"(^HRB .*?\d{5}\s+\S+\.)")
```

**EDIT:**

Modified regex to work with below text too

> HRB 760467: APC One UG (haftungsbeschränkt), Rottenburg am Neckar, Lilienthalweg 3, 72108 Rottenburg am Neckar. Gesellschaft mit beschränkter Haftung. Gesellschaftsvertrag vom 22.03.2017. Geschäftsanschrift: Lilienthalweg 3, 72108 Rottenburg am Neckar. Gegenstand: Entwicklung, Entwicklungsberatung, Herstellung sowie Vertrieb von elektronischen Produkten. Stammkapital: 1.500,00 EUR.

```
Regex.Match(txt, @"(<br>HRB .*?\d{5}\s+[\w\-\s]+\.)")
```

Comment: I'll play around with it a little, thank you already. You may take a look here for the whole thing. https://pastebin.com/cBHHuENL

Comment: I changed it to: `<br>HRB .*?\d+\s+\S+\.` as I have {5} can be 4/3/2 too. Also <br> because it finds 2 matches otherwise. But still somework and some not: `{<br>HRB 760467: APC One UG (haftungsbeschränkt), Rottenburg am Neckar, Lilienthalweg 3, 72108 Rottenburg am Neckar. Gesellschaft mit beschränkter Haftung. Gesellschaftsvertrag vom 22.03.2017. Geschäftsanschrift: Lilienthalweg 3, 72108 Rottenburg am Neckar. Gegenstand: Entwicklung, Entwicklungsberatung, Herstellung sowie Vertrieb von elektronischen Produkten. Stammkapital: 1.500,00 EUR.}` I need right before the `. Gesellschaft mit ` starts

Comment: @iDraGoN so does your text always contain the `<br>`?

Comment: Your edited version is very nice, it works perfectly! Now I'm struggling with the name of the owner. Sometimes regex for city isn't working and it somehow takes the address as city, but I ignore those cases.. it's like 20/400

Comment: so got the names working.. the only thing doesn't work properly is the city - as I have this stupid regex I need to have at least 5 chars in the city name to cover "-" or " ". But if the name is like 3 chars long it takes the address as city.. Do you have an idea how to fix this? 

`, \w+.\w+.\w+,`
`<br>HRB 5734: Urban Crudes UG (haftungsbeschränkt), Hof, Leopoldstraße 7, 95030 Hof.`

Comment: @iDraGoN Please post another question for that

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on German addresses, but from the examples you give it appears you just need everything from the "HRB" through the word followed by five digits.  In regex,

```
HRB .+ \d{5} \w+
```

[Play with it here](https://regex101.com/r/CDgaaU/1).

Comment: With the first try I get as result "HRB 760466: Europa Institut International Private College of Languages and Business GmbH, Reutlingen, Unter den Linden 15, 72762 Reutlingen. Gesellschaft mit beschränkter Haftung. Gesellschaftsvertrag vom 10.01.2017 mit Änderung vom 22.03.2017. Geschäftsanschrift: Unter den Linden 15, 72762 Reutlingen"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe RegEx isn't the right tool?  Split on commas and parse each block of comma-delimited text.  Then maybe, just maybe, you can determine what is in each block of text with a target RegEx that can tell you if that substring is of that type.  Still don't know how to handle when multiple patterns match.

Comment: That would be a possibility, but as there are way more commas, I need to regex at least the part "HRB.... 12345 Bonn" for example. The whole thing is to see here: https://pastebin.com/cBHHuENL